# Find curve at the intersection of two level surfaces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametric, tangent-line

Let C be the curve at the intersection of two level surfaces M(x, y, z) = 5 and N(x,y,z) = 0, passing through a point P (1,1,1). Let $M(x, y, z) = 2x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2$ and $N(x, y, z) = xy-z$. Find curve C in the parametric form <x(t), y(t), z(t)>.

I am quite stuck on this one. I could let $z = xy$ and then plugging that into M I'd have $2x^2 + y^2 + 2x^2y^2 = 5$, and I have no idea what would be good ways to parametrize that.

Another way is to let $y=z/x$, in which case I end up with $2x^4 + (2z^2-5)x^2+z^2 = 0$, but again, I'm quite stuck. Any help would be really appreciated!

Or, if it is impossible to find the curve C, the question I'm working on actually asks for the tangent line to curve C at P if x'(0) = 3. If this makes things easier, how exactly is using this tangent more useful?

Comment: I would parameterize $M(x,y,z)=5$ first.

Comment: @MatthewPilling—hmm would that look like $x= \sqrt{5/2}\cos t$, $y=\sqrt(5)\sin t$,..? I'm not too sure about z, still

Comment: If you want to parameterize $2x^2+y^2+2z^2=5$ you would first write this as $$\bigg(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{2z}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg)^2=1$$ Notice that this resembles the equation of the unit sphere. That being said, set $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{5}}=\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}}=\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),\frac{2z}{\sqrt{5}}=\cos(\phi)$$ where $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ and $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi).$ Use this parameterization and the fact that $z=xy$ to parameterize the intersection of the level sets you're looking for. However, the answers provided are better.

Comment: If you use the fact that $z=xy$ and do some trigonometry you get $$\theta=2\arcsin\Bigg(\frac{2\cos(\phi)}{\sqrt{5}\sin^2{(\phi)}}\Bigg)$$ Replacing $\theta$ with $2\arcsin\Bigg(\frac{2\cos(\phi)}{\sqrt{5}\sin^2{(\phi)}}\Bigg)$ in the parameterization of $M(x,y,z)=5$ outlined above gives you another parameterization of your curve. Note the domain of this paramaterization is the collection of $\phi\in [0,\pi]$ such that $\bigg|\frac{2\cos(\phi)}{\sqrt{5}\sin^2{(\phi)}}\bigg|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It often helps to visualize the situation:

[image]

First, eliminate $z$ from your two equations (quite simple... just look at your second equation and plug $z$ into your first equation). Solve that first equation to get $y(x) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{5-2 x^2}}{\sqrt{2 x^2+1}}$.  (It is quadratic, so you'll get a + and a - solution.)

Now you have your three-dimensional parameterization:  $(x, y(x), z(x,y)) = (x, \pm \frac{\sqrt{5-2 x^2}}{\sqrt{2 x^2+1}}, \pm x \frac{\sqrt{5-2 x^2}}{\sqrt{2 x^2+1}})$.

Note especially that this curve includes the point $(1,1,1)$, as you can verify by simple substitutions of $x=1$.

(Note that $-2 \leq x \leq 2$.)

Comment: thank you—but one thing I'm curious about is whether it contains the point (1,1,1), because when x=1, y and z do not correspond to 1. Also, if curve C crosses P at t=0, would I need to change the parameterisations?

Comment: Just try simple substitution!

Comment: umm I'm not really sure what substitution you mean, although I think I might sort of know it... could you elaborate

Comment: Substitution!  Let $x=1$.  Then see what are the values for $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate $2z^2.$ We have $5-2x^2-y^2=2x^2y^2\Rightarrow y^2=\frac{5-2x^2}{1+2x^2}.$ We take the positive square root since in a neighborhood of $(1,1,1),\ y>0.$  Then we may take $(t, \sqrt{\frac{5-2t^2}{1+2t^2}},t\sqrt{\frac{5-2t^2}{1+2t^2}}).$ This paramterization is valid for $t\in [-\sqrt {5/2},\sqrt {5/2}].$

Comment: thank you—but one thing I'm curious about is whether it contains the point (1,1,1), because when x=1, y and z do not correspond to 1. Also, if curve C crosses P at t=0, would I need to change the parameterisations?

Comment: I think they do. And if $t=0,\ y= \sqrt{5},\ z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation $2x^2 + y^2 + 2 x^2 y^2 = 5$  put $x = r \cos t$, $y = \sqrt{2} \,r \sin t$, get $r = \frac{\sqrt{5} }{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + 5\sin^2 2 t} } }$, and  the parametrization
$$\left( \frac{\sqrt{5} \cos t}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + 5\sin^2 2 t} } } , \frac{\sqrt{10}\sin t}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + 5\sin^2 2 t} } } \right)$$

Note that $t= \tan^{-1} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ maps to $(1,1)$.